# Resolution and screens not detected properly

Tags: 12.04, laptop, display, resolution, intel-graphics

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop with integrated Intel graphics (Intel i5 460M CPU). The screen resolution is set to 1024x768 and can only be changed to 800x600, while my screen is 1366x768.

I have secondary NVIDIA graphics and Optimus installed and working. There's also a 1920x1080 display connected via HDMI which I'd like to configure for extended desktop (it's mirrored now). Disconnecting the external display doesn't solve the problem.

I've tried generating new xorg.conf with `Xorg -configure` but it failed with a following message:

```
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices
```

It still had dropped a file called `xorg.conf.new` in my home directory. I've copied it to `/etc/X11`, but it didn't help.

Ubuntu 12.10 did run in 1366x768 with mirrored displays, but it switched to 1024x768 instantly after login.

Some info:

```
gronostaj@GBUNTU:~$ sudo xrandr
[sudo] password for gronostaj: 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0* 
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Jockey doesn't detect any drivers that could be used, but it did on clean 12.04 install. After the first update there are no drivers available.

Do you guys have any idea how to get it working as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this seems obvious now as I've found the solution.

For some reason 12.04 couldn't find a 16:9 resolution that both screens could handle. 12.10 did work on the login screen, but not later - I still don't know why.

I've tried the daily build of 13.04 and it did work well with 1366x768 on both displays, so I decided to try setting up mirrored desktop. And it did work well.

The solution was to uncheck the "Mirror displays" box and now everything works perfectly on 12.04.

[image: Display settings, uncheck "Mirror displays" - problem solved.]