# two monitors without mirroring

Tags: multiple-monitors, cinnamon, split

I have a trouble - I have ubuntu 13.04 with Cinnamon installed, and when I connect to monitor, it makes this:

[image]

I want it to make two split monitors with same dimensions. Is it possible to make it? My graphic card ATI RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series] (source: HWINFO)

When I connect to second monitor (even monitor even projector), the first monitor devides to thirds. The right third displays part of content that should be on second display (rest of content displays corectly, but without this part), and don't work properly. Here is scheme:

[image]

---

HWINFO:
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "ATI RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x791f "RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]"

I havent installed any extra driver (maybe thats the problem??)

XRANDR said this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2080 x 800, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 800x600+1280+200 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0*    60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
LVDS connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800       59.9*+
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4
```

Havent found any xorg.conf file in /etc/

Comment: are you still looking for help with this?

Comment: Hi. This problem solved by reinstalling sys. Now finally solved by buing new laptop :)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the resolution of each monitor separately. Problem is, what I see from the screenshot (jásej jásej... zdravím) you want to use an data-projector as second monitor. Projectors usually has lower resolution than your display. Therefore you have to decrease resolution of your primary display or to buy a new projector with higher resolution ability.

Not every time projectors are correctly detected and then display offers just a basic resolutions, regardless the projector offers more resolutions or not. Try to play with display resolution settings.

try to follow this questions: [Resolution and screens not detected properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252129/resolution-and-screens-not-detected-properly) , [Monitor not detected - low resolution only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82532/monitor-not-detected-low-resolution-only)

Additionally, you can prepare some scripts which can switch your resolutions flexible there and back. Employ xrandr to setup proper modes. For example following command will put my external display right of the main notebook display

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --right-of LVDS-0
```

this script will run cloning of the notebook display on VGA

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --same-as LVDS-0
```

and this will switch my VGA off:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --off
```

You should use output names specific to your system. You can add specific resolutions to each output into the command. Good answers how to do that are here: [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)

**Edit:** Now I understand your problem better. I found something about similar problem here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2006533 , but without clear solution. So you are not the only one. Seems like for cloning displays, the external monitor forces wrong resolution to your notebook display. It would be necessary to know more about your system:

1. What is your graphics card?
2. Did you install specific drivers as Catalyst for Nvidia?
3. what is the result of `xrandr` command when second display is connected and cloning and what is the result when second display is not connected?
4. is there any `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (or on the paths listed here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/xorg.conf.5.html ) and if yes, what is the content?

**Edit2**: the xrandr result should be OK, I see your LVDS as primary display and VGA-0 (should be) shifted 1280 pixels ríght and 200 pixels up, means lower corner if both monitors should be the same. There should be no reason why the part of second (VGA) monitor is displayed on your notebook display. Possible is the driver bug, but it is not clear if you have Ubuntu 13.04 as you wrote in the question or 13.10 as you wrote in a comment bellow. Please correct.

Comment: I didnt explain it enough. If i make both monitors on one resolution, the deviding line moves to third quater of my first monitor, so i need to do it this way (its the best result ive reached)

Comment: L- @user1980807: I do not understand, what you mean. Ideally, extend your question in Czech language and I will translate it back to English... and you will get your answer.

Comment: Ive added these informations to post. Installing Catalyst is not possible to my OS version (Ub 13.10) - it returns error on installation (hope, missing that is not problem)

Comment: Now, Ive got installed Lin Mint 8., and it worked sucessfully, but it didnt accept some SW I need. I've upgraded to newest and it's same as on ubuntu. Any Idea?

Comment: Your question is not specific about the version, that's the problem... Now it is more clear, that you upgraded to 13.10, please confirm.

Comment: Well my system is now LinuxMint 15 (olivia) with gnome 3.6.3 on linux 4.7, but it appears same as Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10 (even same as o older 12.04 and 12.10 which I've tried) Really dont know why...

Comment: looks like hardware over software and driver over settings problem... Try to install catalyst drivers from ATI downloaded package. form http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy1&os=Linux%20x86 for 32 bit linux or here http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy1&os=Linux%20x86_64 for 64 bit linux

Comment: Really dont know whats up, but installation still results in error.
Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:i686:lib::none:3.8.0-19-generic; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro

Comment: I see from your kernel version you have a ubuntu 13.04 equivalent, so you can try some steps for ubuntu 13.04. But Ubuntu uses 3.8.0-19.29, and its not the same. by investigation i have found, that AMD dropped the support for your card in new catalyst 9.4 drivers and therefore you will need kernel version 2.6.28 (or earlier) (http://digresource.com/what-is-this-error-when-trying-to-install-ati-video-driver-188330.html). Unfortunatelly it is about Linux Mint, so its  not anymore relevant directly to Ubuntu, but it is more specific to any Debian based distribution.

Comment: So, what I can do now? Is there any solution for it? Thank you for advice :)

Comment: follow this link, it says it is fully supported... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver , if nothing works, try binary driver https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI